# Apache Ignite - Encryption for Persistent Data

Tags: ignite

Is there a way to do Data Encryption of persistent data in Ignite? I am using Spring Boot Ignite Nodes. I tried to do [TDE](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/security/tde) but landed up with following error:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Using encryption is not allowed for not persistent cache [cacheName=student, groupName=null, cacheType=USER]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.ValidationOnNodeJoinUtils.validate(ValidationOnNodeJoinUtils.java:422) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.createCacheContext(GridCacheProcessor.java:1201) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.prepareCacheContext(GridCacheProcessor.java:1995) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$null$6a5b31b9$1(GridCacheProcessor.java:1830) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$8(GridCacheProcessor.java:1754) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheProcessor.lambda$prepareStartCaches$926b6886$1(GridCacheProcessor.java:1827) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.lambda$null$1(IgniteUtils.java:11138) ~[ignite-core-2.8.1.jar:2.8.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_292]
```

Answer (score 0):

TDE encrypts data that's on disk. The error says you're trying to enable encryption on a memory-only cache.

Comment: how do I encrypt data on memory only cache then? I have used the cache config to persist cache to a particular table

Comment: To use TDE you need to use [Native Persistence](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/persistence/native-persistence). It doesn't work on a memory-only table. You can encrypt a specific column using the [ENCRYPT/DECRYPT functions](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-reference/numeric-functions#encrypt).